# Tikz Drawing Arrow between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,2.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (A) {A};
\draw (5,0) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (B){B};
\draw (5,1.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (C) {C};
\draw (5,3) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (D) {D};
\draw (5,4.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (E) {E};

\draw[-latex] (A) -| (B);


\end{tikzpicture}
```

I managed to draw the boxed per my requirement, I want the arrow to connect to the left side of the box B. Not sure how to do it. 
Regards
Aku

Comment: I used @Stefan's solution it is producing results as shown in the left side attached image. I would like to produce as shown in the right side of the image. 

    \draw[-latex] (A.east) |- (B.west);
    \draw[-latex] (A.east) |- (C.west);
    \draw[-latex] (A.east) |- (D.west);
    \draw[-latex] (A.east) |- (E.west);

thanks ![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/wpnqe.jpg

Comment: this would be a good new question. In this position here, it's an *answer*. That's not how this Question&Answer site works (it's not a web forum). It would be great if you re-post this as a separate question. Of course you may additionally link to here.

Comment: @Stefan I will ask as a new question. I am still learning. Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use anchors, for example:

```
\draw[-latex] (A.east) -- (B.west);
```

For lines going down and then right, use `|-`

```
\draw[-latex] (A.south) |- (B.west);
```