# Tikz - How to connect nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, node-connections

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,2.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (A) {A};
\draw (5,0) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (B){B};
\draw (5,1.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (C) {C};
\draw (5,3) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (D) {D};
\draw (5,4.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (E) {E};

\draw[-latex] (A.east) |- (B.west);
\draw[-latex] (A.east) |- (C.west);
\draw[-latex] (A.east) |- (D.west);
\draw[-latex] (A.east) |- (E.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

With Stefan's help I manage to draw the lines that travel straight and make 90 turn. The output of that solution is on the left side of the attached image. My goal is to produce result as shown on the right side of the image. 
I already asked similar question earlier, check here [Tikz Drawing Arrow between nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8099/tikz-drawing-arrow-between-nodes/8823#8823) [image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way would be to add a stage at the start of the arrows that goes horizontally for a bit:

```
\draw[-latex] (A.east) -- ++(1,0) |- (B.west);
```

(adjust the `1` to get the length you want).

This does mean that the first part of the line would get drawn 4 times.  It may not show (I don't know).  To avoid that, you could draw it only the once; thus the later lines would be:

```
\draw[-latex] (A.east) ++(1,0) |- (C.west);
```

An alternative would be to put a `coordinate` node at that point:

```
\draw (A.east) -- ++(1,0) coordinate (div);
\draw[-latex] (div) |- (B.west);
\draw[-latex] (div) |- (C.west);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can create a new command with an intermediate point

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\newcommand{\myline}[2]{
\path(#1.east) --(#2.west)  coordinate[pos=0.4](mid);
\draw[-latex] (#1.east) -| (mid) |- (#2.west);
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,2.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (A) {A};
\draw (5,0) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (B){B};
\draw (5,1.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (C) {C};
\draw (5,3) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (D) {D};
\draw (5,4.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (E) {E};

\myline{A}{E}
\myline{A}{D}
\myline{A}{C}
\myline{A}{B}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: line with intermediate point]

Comment: The best way to mark code here is to select it and press the `{}` button (or Ctrl-K), rather than by enclosing it in `<pre>...</pre>`

Comment: `every node/.style ={minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw}` would be nice too !